# redirect html 5 form using javascript

Tags: html

Hi all  i have login form design in html 5 and depending on login details enterd it shoud redirect to respective page. i am checking login details in javascript and redirecting page using javascript but its not working at all. page is not getting redirect.

```
<form id="html5form" method="post">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="tbl_form">
                <tbody>                        
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Username: <span>*</span></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" name="txtLoginNm" id="txtLoginNm" class="field" required="required" placeholder="Enter Username" onkeydown="fnAdmPassword(e);"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>Password: <span>*</span></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" name="txtPwd" id="txtPwd" maxlength="20" class="field" required="required" Placeholder="Enter Password" onkeydown="fnAdmPassword(e);"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            &nbsp;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" title="Login" value="Login" name="Login" class="buttom" onclick="javascript:return fnlogin();" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </form>
```

////  and the javascript function is as follows

```
function fnlogin()
{
   if ((document.getElementById("txtLoginNm").value == "") && (document.getElementById("txtPwd").value == ""))
    {
        alert("Please enter Username & Password!");
    }
else if ((document.getElementById("txtLoginNm").value == "user155") && (document.getElementById("txtPwd").value == "user155"))
    {
        window.location.href = "comp-admin/u_dashboard.shtm";
    }
    else if ((document.getElementById("txtLoginNm").value == "superadmin") && (document.getElementById("txtPwd").value == "superadmin")) {

        window.location.href = "s-admin/edit-profile.shtm";
    }
else (alert("Invalid username or password!"))
  }
```

please tell me why page is not getting redirect

Comment: can you also post your function fnAdmPassword(e);

Comment: `onclick="javascript:return fnlogin();"` you have to remove `javascript:` part here.

Answer (score 0):

This is why it is not redirecting

```
<input type="submit" title="Login" value="Login" name="Login" class="buttom" onclick="javascript:return fnlogin();" />
```

You have to make 2 changes here

1. Change button type from submit to just button, because then submit functionality is taking precedence and you have no action url defined
2. Remove **javascript:** from your call. (As also suggested by **Jan Hančič** in comments)

So try this

```
<input type="button" title="Login" value="Login" name="Login" class="buttom" onclick="return fnlogin();" />
```